# Using the basic heroku database plan with multiple apps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

This should be easy, but I have not been able to find a straightforward answer.

If I subscribe to Heroku's starter database basic plan (the $9/mo option, as of this writing) will I be able to deploy multiple Rails applications, each with its own db, and still pay $9/mo as long as the grand sum of rows across all dbs stays below 1M?

Thanks,
Giuseppe

Comment: From several comments and even a vote to close this question, there seems to be a misunderstanding. I am not planning to share a single database between multiple apps. As I wrote, I would like to run different apps, EACH WITH ITS OWN DB, and still only pay $9/mo, as long as all dbs combined do not exceed the 1M row cap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at Heroku's Postgresql page and choose the Basic plan (https://addons.heroku.com/heroku-postgresql), you are prompted to select an app. The button next to it says "Add Basic for $9/mo". I've worked with paid database plans on Heroku before and it's always been "(monthly fee) per database per app" in my experience.

Comment: Thanks, I saw that one, but my question is different; I am not planning to access the same database from different apps; I am trying to figure out if the basic plan allows you to run different apps, each with its own database, so long as the total number of rows from all dbs combined does not exceed the plan's limit of 1 million.

Comment: Benjamin, the second part of your answer is what I was looking for. It matches friism's answer, but came in first. So, I will choose yours, as long as you remove the first part, which is confusing as it answers a completely different question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple apps and want each of those apps to have access to a basic database plan, you have to add a $9 basic plan add-on to each of those apps, even if the aggregate row count is lower than 1M.